# MySQL Syntax Error: 'LOAD' (load) is not valid input at this position

Tags: mysql

I want to create a simple script to clear the contents of a table and then import the contents of a .csv file into the cleared table. When I run the `TRUNCATE` line by itself, it works. When I run the remaining portion, starting at `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` by itself, it works. But, when I combine the two and try to clear the table and then import the .csv file within the same script, I get an error on line 2.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Test_Company.inventory data
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE /Users/Test.User/Desktop/Data/Inventory Data.csv 
INSERT INTO TABLE Test_Company.inventory data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'

IGNORE 1 LINES
```

---

> MySQL Syntax Error: 'LOAD' (load) is not valid input at this position
>
> Response: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
>   '/Users/Test.User/Desktop/Data/Inventory Data.csv'' at line 3
>   Operation failed with exitcode 1

Comment: MySQL statements should be terminated by a semicolon. What happens if you add one at the end of your TRUNCATE TABLE statement?

Comment: This is two statements, not one. You can't just keep chaining.

Comment: Looks like adding the semicolon at the end of the TRUNCATE TABLE statement did the trick. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, I was using a driver to make the request and I solved it doing the request in one line, for example, if I wanted:

```
SELECT *
FROM db.my_table
```

I wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM db.my_table
```

All the request in one line.

Comment: You might want to make it more apparent that before and after is different. Right now the two statements are the same.